# Setting a cookie in flask

Tags: python, cookies, flask

I am trying to create a cookie in flask. The partial example in the manual is:

```
resp = make_response(render_template(...))
resp.set_cookie(’username’, ’the username’)
```

So I implement it as:

```
resp = render_template('show_entries.html', AO_sInteger = session.get('AO_sInteger'))
resp.set_cookie('AO_sInteger', AO_sInteger)
```

The system then returns this error:

```
File "...\Flaskr101.py", line 19, in add_entry
resp.set_cookie('AO_sInteger', AO_sInteger)
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'set_cookie'
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: resp is not a response object here

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the manual `resp` is:

```
resp = make_response(render_template(...))
```

and in your code it is:

```
resp = render_template('show_entries.html', 
                        AO_sInteger = session.get('AO_sInteger'))
```

Make it a proper response object by using `make_response`:

```
from flask import make_response
resp = make_response(render_template('show_entries.html',
                                      AO_sInteger = session.get('AO_sInteger')))
```

Comment: `rented_template` returns an Unicode string. Cookies are set on Response objects, not a strings. Only after you make that object (as shown above) you can call its [set_cookie](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Response.set_cookie) method. Alternatively, instantiate the [flask.Response](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Response) class directly.